# svg elements as buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm currently working on a website project for one of my classes and I've run into a bit of a roadblock.

I created an image with certain checkpoints embedded and would like for my user to be able to click on those checkpoints and trigger a modal or an in-window box with a fieldset.

I'm going to try an include everything relevant!

I cut out most of the stuff in the middle, so my base code kinda looks like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button-trigger').click(function(){
            $(this).next('#button-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
                $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
            else 
                $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
        })
    });
</script>

<svg version>
    <style type>
        <image style>pregenerated things</image>
        <g id="Element1">
            <button><g>pregenerated things specifically about the image</g></button>
        </g>
        <g id="Element2">
            <a id="button-trigger" href="#"><g>pregenerated things specifically about the image</g></a>
            <div id="button-content">
                <fieldset id="input">
                <input type="text">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </g>
    </style type>
<svg>
```

When trying to turn those  tags into a button like I've shown, the element just disappears and I'm really not sure what to do. When using the jquery, I can keep the element visible and it is linked, but it doesn't bring up the window that I've created in CSS (I copy and pasted that code from another window that is actively working).

Any thoughts? Is there a better way to do this? I'm just googling things and trying to brute force it into my website to make it functional.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what exactly you want?

Comment: div must go in foreignObject and why is everything in a style element?